# How can i optimize mu voxel engine with Babylon.js

Tags: web, voxel, babylonjs

I'm working since this morning on a little web project (you can find it [here](http://babylon.whiteplay.fr/)) : build a small voxel engine (with textures like Minecraft) with Babylon JS.
I made a small world (size 50 * 50), without blocks below other (just the first layer to walk).
I made a similar project with Java, how can i optimise my project ? Because it's lagging.
With Java, i had to :
- Disable the display of inner faces of cubes (I know "backFaceCulling = true;" but it's only working on blocks that haven't got one image per faces but one image for all faces).
- Disable the display of faces when a block is right next to it.
- Use VBO.
- Make a big object grass(composed by all my grass block than make multiple grass cube).

Do you know how can i do this 4 points ? (and oter way to optimize) ?
PS : All of my code source is in [this](http://babylon.whiteplay.fr/js/main.js) main, do you wan't me to write it here ?

################################### EDIT #########################################

Ok so to make a cube, i've got in my img/block/ folder plg files or other folder. All named by an id (0, 1, 2 ...) If i's a folder, it's contain 6 jpg files (each faces of a block). So this is the code to do this :

```
function readAllCube(scene, tab, nb){
    for(var cpt=0; cpt<=nb; cpt++){
        tab.push(new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("cube"+cpt, scene));
        tab[cpt].backFaceCulling = true;
        switch(cpt){
            case 2:
                tab[cpt].reflectionTexture = new BABYLON.CubeTexture("img/block/"+cpt+"/"+cpt, scene);
                tab[cpt].reflectionTexture.coordinatesMode = BABYLON.Texture.SKYBOX_MODE;
                break;
            default:
                tab[cpt].diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("img/block/"+cpt+".png", scene);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

So i'll have a tab of texture. But when my texture is made of multiple image, i don't know how to rdisable drawing into it (inner faces).

I allso don't find how to make a custom mesh, from all of my cube. I think it's faster to render 1 custom mesh than 625 blocks right ?

If i do that, maybe i think i'll be able to remove faces which are hidden by right next other blocks.

Comment: Come on, we don't do your homework! See [ask] and share a [mcve]!